# IPv6 DHCP Configuration

Tags: dhcp, ipv6

I want to set up an IPv6 only network for testing. However, I can't find any HOWTOs or information on setting up DHCP to autoconfigure IPv6 DNS server addresses etc. I use radvd on a ubuntu server to autoconfigure host addresses and I'm led to believe no clients yet support the RDNSS option.

Can someone point me in the right direction for DHCPv6 setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original ISC DHCP software package includes IPv6 support for DHCPv6 since the 4.x releases, with basic DHCPv6 server, client and relay functionality.

https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/new-features-4.1.0

ISC DHCP 4.1.x will have several new DHCPv6 features that were not in DHCP 4.0.x. These new features include:

- Support for the rapid-commit option on the client side
- Prefix Delegation support
- IA_TA address support
- A basic DHCPv6 relay agent
- basic DHCPv6 Leasequery support

Comment: Are there any tutorials or HOWTO's to configure ISC's DHCP server for IPv6? I've not been able to find any

Answer (score 4):

All you need is a IP address calculator like sipcalc.
Well, on CentOS/RHEL/Fedora you can fetch the dhcpv6 package using yum like this:

```
$ sudo yum install dhcpv6
```

On Debian/Ubuntu and others you can get source code from a git repository:

```
$ git clone git://git.fedorahosted.org/dhcpv6.git
```

After, setting the dhcpv6 find here an example of the dhcpv6 server configuration:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/dhcp6s.conf
```

interface eth1 {
    server-preference 255;
    renew-time 60;
    rebind-time 90;
    prefer-life-time 130;
    valid-life-time 200;
    allow rapid-commit;
    option dns_servers 2002:c22:fddf:0:192:168:16:253 dns.domain.tld;

```
link AAA {
    pool{
        range 2002:c22:fddf:0::1 to 2002:c22:fddf:0::ffff/64;
        prefix 2002:c22:fddf:0::/64;
    };
```

};
};

You may replace 2002:c22:fddf:0:192:168:16:253 by your DNS server IPv6 address and dns.domain.tld by your domain. In link point, setup your network range and your Subnet prefix.
After, you can find here an example of he dhcpv6 client (dhcp6c) configuration:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/dhcp6c.conf
```

interface eth0 {
        send rapid-commit;
        request domain-name-servers;
};

Let's start the daemon:

```
$ sudo service dhcpv6 start
```

At last do some test in client side:

```
$ dhcp6c -f eth0
```