# DHCP in IPV6 Environment

Tags: dhcp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IPv6 DHCP Configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/77994/ipv6-dhcp-configuration)

I want to know the difference for the DHCP implementation in IPv4 environment and IPv6 environment?

Until now we are used an IPv4 DHCP client and an IPv4 DHCP server, but now I want to change the implementation to support IPv6 environment. I am new to network side.

What are the important functionalities going to change in DHCP environment?

Answer (score 2):

For fully automatic configuration of clients in an IPv6 environment you don't actually need DHCPv6 at all! It's possibly to sensibly configure IPv6 hosts using something like [radvd](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/hints-daemons-radvd.html) to offer stateless auto configuration. (There is an option for recursive DNS resolvers, but Windows doesn't support it yet AFAIK and [rdnssd](http://rdnssd.linkfanel.net/) is needed to support it on Linux).

For the most part DHCPv6, which can be used to offer IPv6 leases is [essentially the same](https://serverfault.com/questions/77994/ipv6-dhcp-configuration). There's a flag in the router advertisements that tells hosts if they should use DHCPv6 in addition to the stateless configuration.

Comment: Exactly, many people use stateless autoconfig to give out the address and default gateway. Then the flag in the router advertisement tells the client to ask DHCPv6 for the other information, like DNS servers and such.